# How to use Hudson / Jenkins parameterized value in the CollabNet File Release name

Tags: jenkins, hudson, collabnet

I have a parameterized value for my Release name.  When I try to use that value in the CollabNet File Release add-in for the Release value, it gives me the following error:

CollabNet FileRelease: Critical Error: releaseId cannot be found for ${RELEASE}.  Setting build status to UNSTABLE (or worse).

I've tried many permutations to reference the variable.  I've also verified that it properly resolves the variable value by placing it in another area of the build.  It looks like the CollabNet plugin won't resolve the value.  Has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: AFAIK, the plugin will not create a file release for you, it will only upload files to the release.  So it might be complaining simply that the release does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Without checking: that plugin might not expand configuration field values. In that case, only solution is to fix the plugin (not hard if it is an open source plugin).

But first you should check that the parameter is really set. Undefined parameter is left as is, not replaced with empty string, so you would get that error in that case too. Parameters are also set as environment variables, so simplest way to check by adding build step:

- On windows: "execute windows batch command" with command `echo RELEASE is %RELEASE%`
- On unix: "execute shell command" with command `echo RELEASE is $RELEASE`